# When will [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] return NO

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My iPhone app is using the MFMailComposeViewController class to send an in-app email with an attachment.
The app will only attempt to display the mail composer dialog if the "canSendMail" method of class MFMailComposeViewController returns true (YES). Specifically, if the following method returns YES, it shows the mail composer, otherwise the user is presented with an error alert dialog stating that there are no email accounts set up on the device:

```
- (BOOL)canDeviceSendEmail
{
    Class mailClass = (NSClassFromString(@"MFMailComposeViewController"));
    return mailClass != nil && [mailClass canSendMail];
}
```

A team of testers have reported that they get this error alert dialog, even when email accounts are set up on the device. The tester used an iPhone 3G with OS 3.1.3. Therefore the MFMailComposeViewController class must have existed, and the "canSendMail" method must have returned NO.

My question is therefore: apart from the case when there are no email accounts set up on the device, in what other circumstances can the "canSendMail" method return NO?

~ Thanks

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If at least one email account is enabled on the device, the following call should return YES:

```
[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]
```

Conversely, if all accounts are disabled/removed, it will return NO.

Comment: Old but this still applied today; it doesn't work with third party email clients, only with Apple default email client.

Answer (score 12):

For `+canSendMail` to return YES the default account must be set-up *for sending emails*.

(Internally, `+[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]` calls `+[MailAccountProxy defaultMailAccountForDelivery]`, which finds the first mail account being `-isDefaultDeliveryAccount`.)

Comment: Ah, interesting point. I tried removing the (outgoing) SMTP server from the email account. It opened the email composer window, and the email stayed in the account's Outbox, so +[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] still returned YES.  The only way to make it return NO, was when all email accounts were either disabled or completely removed. Is there another way an account would not be able to send emails, so that canSendMail returns NO?

Answer (score 9):

In addition to an email account not being setup on a device, `canSendMail` also returns `NO` when an MDM profile is installed and configured to not allow third party apps to send mail. In this case you must use `openURL:` with a `mailto:` URL in order to launch Mail.app and optionally fill in the to, cc, bcc, subject, and body field.

mailto: RFC

- https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me.

In Device Go setting->Mail,Contacts,Calendar->Accounts

Here you can see no account is added.Now **add account** now go back to your app and you can find its returning yes this time and you are able to send E-mail.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] will return NO when you don't have any mail account on device. In this case you can open mail app by the following code:

```
- (void)openMailApp {
    NSString *recipients = @"mailto:?cc=&subject=";
    NSString *body = @"&body=";
    NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", recipients, body];
    email = [email stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of iOS 10.1, you can enable mail from iCloud first (in Settings). Then sign in to your iCloud account. All the contacts and email should be available in your simulator after those changes.

With the change, I can get `true` from:

```
MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()
```

I am using Xcode 8.1 with Swift 3.

Answer (score 1):

Vladimir's answer without deprecated functions:

```
    NSString *recipients = @"mailto:testingEmail@example.com?subject=emailsubject";

    NSString *body = @"&body=body:";
    NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", recipients, body];
    email = [email stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email] options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't be certain that `MFMailComposeViewController` must have existed because your method doesn't discriminate between `MFMailComposeViewController` not existing and `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]` returning `NO`.

What iPhone OS you're testing on is not relevant; what version of the iPhone SDK your application links against is what determines whether MFMailComposeViewController will be available at runtime.  If you want that class, you need to build with SDK 3.0 or later.

Comment: Thanks for that. The app was built with base SDK 3.1.2 and the iPhone OS Deployment Target is iPhone OS 3.0

Comment: Aha. This technique of setting the iPhone OS Deployment Target separate from the Base SDK and checking at runtime for classes is new to me.  Pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the Messaging Framework? I had a similar issue once and it was only because I forgot to add the correct framework to the XCode project.

Comment: Yes, the MessageUI.framework is included. On my own test device the emailing does work, as long as there's at least one email account, that's enabled. So the MessageUI.framework must be included correctly.