# Launch Apple Mail App from within my own App?

Tags: ios, email

What I already found is

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:"]];
```

But I just want to open the Mail app not only a composer view. Just the mail app in its normal or last state.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try imap or pop instead of mailto?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Apparently Mail application supports 2nd url scheme - `message://` which ( I suppose) allows to open specific message if it was fetched by the application. If you do not provide message url it will just open mail application:

```
NSURL* mailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"message://"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:mailURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:mailURL];
}
```

Comment: Wondering if the Slack app uses this technique. They are launching without a mail compose view

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. The current accepted answer says that this is not possible but using "message//" does open the email app without the compose screen.

Comment: Great to find this! Do you know if we can use that URL scheme so that Mail app opens an e-mail file (_.msg_ from Outlook or similar) giving a URL where the file is hosted? So something like `message://http://domain/file.msg`.

Comment: @AlexMM, I have not tried that, but if you have message url + attachment url that might work

Comment: According to [this post](https://www.macstories.net/tutorials/ios-7-and-mail-message-urls/) Mail app will only open mails that are already downloaded in Mail app. But the thing is if there is any other way to open a mail hosted in some domain. Thanks!

Comment: It may be worth a separate question, I am not sure.

Comment: This is the accepted answer, but still it's undocumented by Apple in https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MailLinks/MailLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH4-SW1 so I'm not really sure it should be the best answer.

Answer (score 48):

```
NSString *recipients = @"mailto:first@example.com?cc=second@example.com,third@example.com&subject=Hello from California!";

NSString *body = @"&body=It is raining in sunny California!";

NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", recipients, body];

email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
```

Comment: This opens in compose view.

Comment: Not working in iOS 11. Can any one help me with this?

Comment: @HardikAmal iOS 11: The problem is that `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is encoding all special characters (including the colon after `mailto`). The solution is either to find a better encoding function or get rid of the encoding line and manually encode the message by substituting %20 for the spaces in the `subject` and `body`.

Answer (score 21):

Swift version of the original Amit's answer:

**Swift 5**

```
func openEmailApp(toEmail: String, subject: String, body: String) {
    guard
        let subject = subject.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed),
        let body = "Just testing ...".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
    else {
        print("Error: Can't encode subject or body.")
        return
    }
    
    let urlString = "mailto:\(toEmail)?subject=\(subject)&body=\(body)"
    let url = URL(string:urlString)!
    
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

**Swift 3.0:**

```
func openMailApp() {
    
    let toEmail = "email@outlook.com"
    let subject = "Test email".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
    let body = "Just testing ...".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
    
    if 
      let urlString = "mailto:\(toEmail)?subject=\(subject)&body=\(body)",
      let url = URL(string:urlString) 
    {
        UIApplication.shared().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

**Swift 2:**

```
func openMailApp() {
    
    let toEmail = "email@outlook.com"
    let subject = "Test email".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet()
    let body = "Just testing ...".stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet()
    
    if let
        urlString = ("mailto:\(toEmail)?subject=\(subject)&body=\(body)")),
        url = NSURL(string:urlString) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: This version actually does not work for me. It seems only the subject and the body should be encoded based on Apple's doc here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MailLinks/MailLinks.html  So the right `urlString` in the answer should be `let urlString = "mailto:\(toEmail)?subject=\(subject.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!)&body=\(body.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!)"`. This code can be refactored to better format and safer code though.

Answer (score 14):

You can open the mail app without using opening the compose view by using the url scheme `message://`

Answer (score 11):

Since the only way to launch other applications is by using their URL schemes, the only way to open mail is by using the mailto: scheme. Which, unfortunately for your case, will always open the compose view.

Comment: @cschuff even now that appears to be true.  I just took another tour through the URL launching mechanism and any related info I could find.  Still limited to launching with the compose view opened.

Comment: unless no Mail accounts are configured, in which case it will open Mail with the default "Welcome to Mail" screen showing iCloud, Exchange, Google, Yahoo!, Aol., Outlook.com, and Other

Comment: Please see alternative answer which does successfully answer the question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29212029/6426003

Answer (score 9):

Run your app on a real device and call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your@email.com"]];
```

Note, that this line takes no effect on simulator.

Comment: +1 for noting that this doesn't work on the simulator

Answer (score 8):

You can launch any app on iOS if you know its URL scheme. Don't know that the Mail app scheme is public, but you can be sneaky and try this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"message:message-id"]];
```

Props to Farhad Noorzay for clueing me into this. It's some bit of reverse engineering the Mail app API. More info here: https://medium.com/@vijayssundaram/how-to-deep-link-to-ios-7-mail-6c212bc79bd9

Comment: Does this still work in iOS 11?  It's only opening Mail for me, not the specific message.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on Amit's answer:
This will launch the mail app, with a new email started. Just edit the strings to change how the new email begins.

```
//put email info here:
NSString *toEmail=@"supp0rt.fl0ppyw0rm@gmail.com";
NSString *subject=@"The subject!";
NSString *body = @"It is raining in sunny California!";

//opens mail app with new email started
NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"mailto:%@?subject=%@&body=%@", toEmail,subject,body];
email = [email stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:email]];
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Xamarin to developer an iOS application, here is the C# equivalent to open the mail application composer view:

```
string email = "yourname@companyname.com";
NSUrl url = new NSUrl(string.Format(@"mailto:{0}", email));
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4 / 5 to open default Mail App without compose view.
If Mail app is removed, it automatically shows UIAlert with options to redownload app :)

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "message:")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5 version:

```
if let mailURL = URL(string: "message:") {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(mailURL) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(mailURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On swift 2.3: open mailbox

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "message:")!)
```

Answer (score 1):

It will open Default Mail App with composer view:

```
NSURL* mailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto://"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:mailURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:mailURL];
}
```

It will open Default Mail App:

```
NSURL* mailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"message://"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:mailURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:mailURL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a scripting bridge. I used this method in my App to directly give the user the option to send e-mail notifications using the built-in `Mail.app`. I also constructed an option to do this directly over SMTP as an alternate.

But since you want to use `Mail.app` method, you can find more information about how to do that solution by following this:

https://github.com/HelmutJ/CocoaSampleCode/tree/master/SBSendEmail

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score -5):

In Swift:

```
let recipients = "someone@gmail.com"
let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:\(recipients)")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
```