# Cannot show modal ViewController in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7

I tried to show system defined viewcontrollers (MFMailComposeViewController, TWTweetComposeViewController,etc..) as a modal view.

But these viewcontrollers dosn't appear in iOS 7(these run in iOS5,iOS6).

Viewcontrollers created by me appear in iOS7(ex.HogeViewController).

I don't call `presentViewController:animated:completion` at `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`.

Does anybody have an idea?

Console logs:

> init Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)"

or

> _serviceViewControllerReady:error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)"

or

> Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for .

TWTweetComposeViewController(doesn't appear)

```
TWTweetComposeViewController *viewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc]init];
viewController.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result){
    NSLog(@"Result : %d",result);
};
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Log

> Result : 0

MFMailComposeViewController(appears a moment and dismiss soon)

```
- (void)send:(NSString*)email{
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        NSArray *toRecipients = @[email];
        [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];

        [picker setSubject:@"Subject"];
        [picker setMessageBody:@"Body" isHTML:NO];
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"error:%@,result:%d",error.description,result);
    }];
}
```

Log

> _serviceViewControllerReady:error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)"
>   Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for .
>   error:(null),result:0

Comment: Can you try to set animated:no on transitions?

Comment: There is no difference about TWTweetComposeViewController.
About MFMailComposeViewController,does not appear ViewController and crash(EXC_BAD_ACCESS).

Comment: I've encountered the exact same problem but only on an iPhone. An iPad does not exhibit the same problem for me. Unless I hear otherwise I believe it's an iOS 7 bug. If you set a breakpoint on the ending delegate method the result for the mail controller is MFMailComposeResultCancelled.

Comment: We are only seeing that on iPhone 5s, currently running iOS 7.0.2 (11A501). Compiling the exact same code and running it on iPhone 5 does not show the issue. Build was 32-bit only, so it's not a 64-bit issue in our app. However, it seems to be a 32- vs 64-bit issue on Apple's side. When compiling our app with arm64, those views display correctly. Can anyone please confirm?

Comment: I am getting the same behavior in the same situations using UIActivityViewController and SLComposeViewController

Comment: see my answer for details

Comment: Related question with similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411489/qlpreviewcontroller-quicklookd-failing-to-load

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Turns out the issue only shows up when customizing UIBarButtons. If we use the following in our 32-bit app running on iPhone 5s, we have the problem:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, 1.0)
                                           forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Leaving out that line works around the problem. We have filed a radar.

Comment: Thank you for response.I removed **[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)];** and fixed this issue!

Comment: I've reported this issue as well as rdar://15165678

Comment: This is insane, I applaud you for finding the bug in Apple's code.

Comment: Same issue here with QLPreviewController. Customizing UIBarButtonItem's titlePosition in versions less than 7 fixed my issue.

Comment: I had the same experience while using the UISearchBar appearance APIs.     [searchBarApperance setPositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(100, 0) forSearchBarIcon:UISearchBarIconClear];

Comment: I removed [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, -3.0f)];
Going to open a radar about that.
iPhone5S / iOS 7.0.x / XCode 5.0

Comment: Brandyn Brosemer's answer helped me: building on 64bit solves the problem.

Answer (score 7):

This is an issue when you do not compile for 64bit (arm64) in your project settings. Though this may not always be an option for some people because currently Google Analytics does not support the 64bit devices.

Comment: and I'm eating my previous words here; had an incorrect build setting, and once that was fixed, and was able to build for 64, this problem went away. Upvoting... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to avoid this issue with some subclassing. I was having the same issue, and in my case the culprit was:

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setSearchTextPositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(15.0f, 0.0f)];
```

I was already using a subclass of UISearchBar anyway, so I changed that to:

```
[[KA_SearchBar appearance] setSearchTextPositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(15.0f, 0.0f)];
```

That's resolved the issue for me. Only tested on an iPhone 5s, iOS 7.0.3.

Comment: Radar'd as rdar://15461545

Answer (score 2):

I am getting the same behavior in the same situations. In my case it turned out to be caused by using the "setSeparatorInset" appearance selector of UITableView. Getting rid of that fixed the problem. This looks like a bug on Apple's end for sure, but at least there is a workaround.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721462/the-mfmailcomposer-is-sometime-giving-error) shows someone having a similar problem and in their case getting rid of a UISearchBar appearance selector fixed it. So something is wrong with some of these UIAppearance selectors.

Answer (score 1):

This post helped me find a solution to a similar issue. But my problem was not related to the tab bar, so I figured I'd share if anyone else comes across this post:

The mail modal opened when tapping a table cell, but would instantly dismiss. In my case, this code caused the problem:

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0]];
```

I deleted it, and everything works!

Answer (score 0):

In My case, following code will cause the same issue on **64bit** machine or simulator. Hope for helping someone met this issue.

```
if ([UITableViewCell instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
    [[UITableViewCell appearance] setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Problem occurs in iPad air (64 bit) when app is not complied for 64 architecture. The problem I encountered was every UIAppearance selector which try to use UIOffsetMake/UIOffsetZero doesn't work properly! 
example

```
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(1.0, 1.0) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

or

```
    [[UITableViewCell appearance] setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5)];
```

I think its a bug in Apple code and I tried few things but nothing works. Better if you can comment out places where you setInsets in UIAppearance selectors

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when use SLComposeViewController to share with Facebook or Twitter using the simulator of 64-Bits or an iPhone 5s, then i delete every line of code that use "appearance, for example [UITableViewCell appearance] or [UIBarButtonItem appearance], and every run ok.

Answer (score 0):

I updated xcode to version 5.1 and it worked ok now.

Comment: Could you provide more detail?

Answer (score 0):

NSXPCConnectionInterrupted = 4097.  I would have your code retry the command as the error looks to be transient.