# iOS application logs : Cocoa error 4097

Tags: ios, ios7.1, uikeyboard, xcode5.1.1

> -[UIKeyboardInputManagerClient handleError:forRequest:] will retry sending handleKeyboardInput:keyboardState:continuation: to keyboard daemon after receiving Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)"

My app logs this message in iOS 7.1 and Xcode 5.1.1. I couldn't find a thing for this,  any suggestion?

Comment: Have you googled: "NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097"?  I see lot's of hits (About 9,180 results). Perhaps this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19119388/451475) will help.

Answer (score 0):

NSXPCConnectionInterrupted = 4097.  I would have your code retry the command as the error looks to be transient.