# Is it possible to switch to the Mail app in iOS?

Tags: ios

My iOS app offers a feature to create a new web service account. Once the account has been created it has to be activated by clicking on a link within a confirmation mail.

**Is it somehow possible to offer the user the option to switch to the mail app once he has completed the registration process?**

**Or in general:** Is it possible to switch to app XY from within my own app?

Of course I know the `MFMailComposeViewController` but this is not about creating a new mail but about switching to the Mail app to receive the confirmation mail.

Comment: Probably duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206596/launch-mail-app-ios-from-my-own-app/ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch Mail app (iOS) from my own app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206596/launch-mail-app-ios-from-my-own-app)

Answer (score -1):

you can do it after server reply's to you

```
   let mailURL = URL(string: "message://")!
   if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(mailURL) {
   UIApplication.shared.open(mailURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: User want to open inbox not maul composer