# Angular, on button press launch email app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Suppose I send a verification code on email and I have a button "check mail" On pressing that I want to just open the email app on the phone directly

edit: trying cordova-app-alunch plugin for it, if you have any suggestions

Comment: Use any Modal and how two buttons and then according decision redirect to relevant path

Comment: okay for "open in app" button, how do I give the path, please help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201917/how-can-i-open-a-url-in-androids-web-browser-from-my-application

Comment: @Wasim the email app, suppose gmail, it should open directly on button press

Comment: You can't do that, that would be a huge security risk. You can write a text that tells users to check their email.

Comment: slack does it too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206596/launch-mail-app-ios-from-my-own-app#:~:text=You%20can%20launch%20mail%20app%20using%20message%3A%2F%2F%20url,sharedApplication%5D%20canOpenURL%3AmailURL%5D%29%20%7B%20%5B%20%5BUIApplication%20sharedApplication%5D%20openURL%3AmailURL%5D%3B%20%7D

Comment: in case u are using capacitor, u can use https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/app-launcher and launch the app by its package name like (com.google.android.gm) for android and maybe for ios...

Comment: thank you, maybe this could work. how to put an url such that on button press it asks what email app to use

Answer (score 1):

[this might help](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/email-composer/?_gl=1*kj4hfz*_ga*NzA5NTM5MDg1LjE2NTYwODAwMjU.*_ga_REH9TJF6KF*MTY1NjA4MDAyNC4xLjAuMTY1NjA4MDAyNC4w)

you can also open new mail and give pre selected info

```js
let email = {
      to: 'max@mustermann.de',
      cc: 'erika@mustermann.de',
      bcc: ['john@doe.com', 'jane@doe.com'],
      attachments: [
        'file://img/logo.png',
        'res://icon.png',
        'base64:icon.png//iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...',
        'file://README.pdf'
      ],
      subject: 'Cordova Icons',
      body: 'How are you? Nice greetings from Leipzig',
      isHtml: true
    }
```

with following you can open and attach the following with one press of a button

```js
// Send a text message using default options
this.emailComposer.open(email);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, however i just want to open email app and not the email compose box

Comment: Answers is for something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [send mail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sendmail) is an node package.

Comment: This package is used for sending out an email, while the author looks for a possibility to open the mail app. How to send an email is clearly not part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it, it navigate to Gmail if logged in.

```
mailto:SomeMail@blabla.example
```