# How to launch the iOS mail app in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplication

I'm creating an iOS application with a password reset feature that sends an email to the user. After sending the email I want to display a `UIAlertController` to the user asking them if they would like to open the mail application.

I've seen various posts on here along the lines of:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "mailto:")
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
```

This works but unfortunately it starts a new message which is not what I want. I only want to launch the application so the user can see their inbox.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not tested myself but maybe this answer will help you:

> Apparently Mail supports a second url scheme `message://` which (I suppose) allows you to open a specific message if it was fetched by your application. If you do not provide a full message url, it will just open Mail:

```
let mailURL = URL(string: "message://")!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(mailURL) {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(mailURL)
}
```

Taken from: [Launch Apple Mail App from within my own App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821934/launch-apple-mail-app-from-within-my-own-app)

Comment: unverschaemt, given that this is a Swift-question, would you be bothered if I edited your answer into Swift?

Comment: does one have to get permission to do this? For example if I wanted to open the gmail app from my app for the sake of verifying a users email, would I need to ask google for permission to open their app from mine?

Comment: to validate a users email you'd better choose a regex and also send a confirmation email if you want to. In any case you can use the url-scheme from third party apps to open them with your content. That's why they made them in the first place. However you can't control like the whole app you have a predefined set of functions you can use from the third party app.

Answer (score 3):

The **Swift 3.0.1** way of just opening the Mail app goes as follows:

```
private func openMailClient() {
    let mailURL = URL(string: "message://")!
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(mailURL) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(mailURL)
    }
}
```

As "dehlen" correctly stated, using the `message://` scheme will only open the mail app, if no further information is provided.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously a few years later...I had to add a completion handler for Xcode 10.2.1 swift 5.

This works perfectly-

```
    let emailURL = NSURL(string: "message://")!

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(emailURL as URL)
    {
        UIApplication.shared.open(emailURL as URL, options: [:],completionHandler: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `UIApplication.shared.openURL()` method has been deprecated and we can use `URL()` directly in place of `NSURL()`, the updated version of this question's answer is:

```
let mailURL = URL(string: "message://")!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(mailURL) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(mailURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work with Xcode 11.5:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.row {     
    case 5:
        openEmailApp(email: "email@gmail.com")
        
    default:
        break
    }
}

func openEmailApp(email: String) {
    if let url = URL(string: "mailto: \(email)") {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```