# iOS Swift: Open Mail app in inbox emails

Tags: ios, swift, email, button

Evening, I'm trying to open the inbox mail of the Mail app from a button action...

In the web I saw that is possibile to open the email app the the EmailComposer object.. but I'm not trying to make a new email, I just want the user checks the emails.

Any tips?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch Apple Mail App from within my own App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821934/launch-apple-mail-app-from-within-my-own-app)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I resolved using the following code:

```
   let mailURL = URL(string: "message://")!
   if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(mailURL) {
       UIApplication.shared.open(mailURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
```