# Open mail app without creating email draft

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have an app that needs to prompt the user to open an email that's just been sent to them. It would be a great feature if it automatically opened the email app for them.

I currently have this code to open the email app and create a new draft email:

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("mailto://"));
```

I need this to run without opening a new email, just take them to their default mail app.

Comment: On iOS it’s possible in Swift by doing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46649692/ios-swift-open-mail-app-in-inbox-emails/46661209

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible to do in a purely cross-platform manner without the `mailto://` URI which all systems understand. If you wanted to just open the mail client, you would have to check if your target OS supports such intent / URI and open it in a platform-specific manner.

**Update:** I have found platform specific solutions for Android and iOS.

**Android**

```
var intent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.email");
StartActivity(intent);
```

**iOS**

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl("message://");
```

**UWP**

In case of UWP `mailto:` seems to be the right option according to [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app#email-uri-scheme). Unfortunately from my testing it does try to create a new e-mail with the built in Outlook Mail app. I will report that as a issue.