# MacOS NSWorkspace.shared.open "The application can’t be opened. -50"

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Following some other [Stack Overflow code examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31787435/1762493) of `NSWorkspace.shared.open()`, I came up with this:

```swift
  @IBAction func mailFileVacuum(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let receiver = sender.alternateTitle
    let sendAddress = String(format: "mailto:%@@filevacuum.com?subject=FileVacuum %@", receiver, receiver).addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!

    NSLog("receiver %@", receiver)

    let mailUrl = URL(string: sendAddress)

    NSLog("mailUrl %@", mailUrl!.absoluteString)

    if NSWorkspace.shared.open(mailUrl!) {
        print("Default browser was successfully opened to send email. ")

    }
  }
```

☝️ that gets us this

[image]

I tried changing the default browser, that's not the issue.

`NSLog(mailUrl)` logs this `mailto%3AFeedback%40filevacuum.com%3Fsubject=FileVacuum%20Feedback`

Look good maybe ...

¿Que Paso?

Comment: @LeoDabus, that was just an example. They're all using `UIApplication.shared().openURL(url)` in that example link. I'm using `NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)` from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be percent encoding the *entire* URL; but rather, its individual components. See the [Apple URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MailLinks/MailLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH4-SW1).

The correctly formatted URL should look like (i.e. `NSLog(mailUrl)` should output):

```
mailto:Feedback@filevacuum.com?subject=FileVacuum%20Feedback
```