# How to open mail app inbox directly in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-linking

Using `Linking.openURL('mailto:')` with expo-linking opens the mail app with a 'compose mail' screen, how can i open the mail app directly on the inbox tab ?

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821934/launch-apple-mail-app-from-within-my-own-app), you can use the `message://` url scheme to achieve this on iOS. If no content is provided, it defaults to the email inbox on iOS.

For android, things are a little trickier. You'll need [expo-intent-launcher](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/intent-launcher/) and a few extra params to complete the hand-off. A complete solution may look something like this:

```js
    import { startActivityAsync, ActivityAction } from 'expo-intent-launcher';

    [...]
    
    if (Platform.OS === "android") {
      const activityAction = "android.intent.action.MAIN";
      const intentParams: IntentLauncher.IntentLauncherParams = {
        category: "android.intent.category.APP_EMAIL",
      };
      IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(activityAction, intentParams);
    } 
    else if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
      Linking.openURL('message://');
    }
```

Be sure to test on real devices if possible since the iPhone simulator doesn't have a mail client installed.

[List of URL schemes on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes)

**Update**: If you don't mind an extra dependency, take a look at [react-native-email-link](https://github.com/includable/react-native-email-link) which has the added benefit of allowing users to select from any installed email client. Neat!