# ios: Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target

Tags: ios7, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am developing an application,the requirement is to open email composer on a button click of UIAlertView.

message which is in message body of email is copied from UITextView. i am using following code snipt:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if (buttonIndex == 0)
  {
      // opening message composer
  }
else
  {
   MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [picker setSubject:@"Test mail"];
    [picker setMessageBody:messageBody.text isHTML:YES];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
  }
}
 // mail compose delegate
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

but the issue is that i am getting error saying Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target. how we can open default mail composer in ios 7?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

As per Apple, You should check is **MFMailComposeViewController** are able to send your mail just before sending

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
     MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [picker setSubject:@"Test mail"];
    [picker setMessageBody:messageBody.text isHTML:YES];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

---

**Swift:**

```
if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() else {
// Send mail code
}
```

Ref : [Apple Dev url](https://developer.apple.com/reference/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)

---

Comment: Guard mechanism rocks!

Comment: but why text message (MFMessageComposeViewController) doesn't need this check? I have a testing device that doesn't have sim card, technically it shouldn't be able to send text, but it works fine (no exception thrown) without the check... why? thanks.

Comment: So, no more testing the send mail UI on the Simulator...?

Comment: Users' device might have no email account configured.  So, testing on simulator can catch the missing guard.  After adding `canSendMail`, we'll have to rely on device testing.

Answer (score 17):

Swift 4 version

```
guard MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() else {
    print("Mail services are not available")
    return
}
sendEmail()
```

Answer (score 11):

Forgetting Mail account configuration in device settings may also lead to this error. Re check whether a mail account is configured in your device or not.