# If Mail is installed Do function , if not Open app store page

Tags: ios, swift, email, url, url-scheme

I'm trying to do what the title says but when i tap the button to open mail  my app crashes when i don't have mail app installed. can you help me sort this out?

## Code:

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "mailto://")!) {
            // Mail is installed. Launch Mail and start function:
            let toRecipients = ["oExample@gmail.com"]

        let mc: MFMailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()

        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self

        mc.setToRecipients(toRecipients)
        mc.setSubject("Why does it crash?")

        mc.setMessageBody("שם הבר: \(CrashNameField.text!) \n\nעיר: \(CrashReasonNameField.text!)", isHTML: false)

        self.present(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else {
            // Mail is not installed. Launch AppStore to install Mail app
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/mail/id1108187098?mt=8")!)
        }
    }
```

## Crash gathered logs :

`libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` crashes on line : `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{` . Extra info : `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target`

Comment: What is the crash?  Which line does it crash on?

Comment: sorry , should have included that in. Its saying : `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` crashes on line : `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{` . Extra info : `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target`

Comment: It looks like all you need to do is check to see if `mc == nil`

Comment: can you show me how can it be done... sorry, I'm still a newbie...

Comment: `if mc != nil { // your existing code } else { // prompt to install mail client }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this way

```
 var picker = MFMailComposeViewController()
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self
        picker.setSubject("Test mail")
        picker.setMessageBody(messageBody.text, isHTML: true)
        present(picker as? UIViewController ?? UIViewController(), animated: true) { _ in }
    }
```

[original post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239056/ios-application-tried-to-present-a-nil-modal-view-controller-on-target)

Comment: I need if the app is not installed it will show an alert or open a link so it won't crash can you help with  that?

Comment: just else condition put this  UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/mail/id1108187098?mt=8")!)

Comment: did you set `<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>mail</string>
</array>`

Comment: still crashing... :(

Comment: check to see if `mc == nil`... how can this be done?

Comment: @RandomGeek check this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Comment: Just What I needed. Awesome!