# iOS - Not able to add attachment, while launching gmail from my app

Tags: ios, gmail, email-client

I am using `MFMailComposeViewController` to Compose email with attachment and it's working fine

Now I want to compose image with attachment with native email client. I am using code below

```
 NSString *customURL =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"googlegmail:///co?to=[t0]&subject=[subject]&body=[body]"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:customURL];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]
         canOpenURL:url])
    {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {

            NSLog(@"%d",success);
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        //not installed, show popup for a user or an error
    }
```

It's working fine with subject and Body, but I am not able to attach attachments(ie:Zip file, screen shots).

**is there any way to add attachment, while using gmail or any other client app.**

Comment: This link could be helpful:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824647/send-an-iphone-attachment-through-email-programmatically

Comment: @Abhishek above link shared by you uses `MFMailComposeViewController `, I don't want to use it, I want to use another email client ie: gmail, yahoo-mail or office

Comment: Have you found a solution on this?