# Swift : Open mailto link in UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, mailto

I am developing an application using UIWebView. Inside the web view I have mailto link and I want to open this link in the mail application of iOS.

That is my entire code of the application

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    //webview.delegate = self;
    webview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.all
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.webview.delegate = self
     let webURL = URL(string: "http://www.collegiodeirettori.net/palio/")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: webURL!)

    webview.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    webview.scrollView.bounces = false




}

func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {


    print(request)
    let stringaURL = try! String(contentsOf: request.url!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii)

    if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.linkClicked{
        if((stringaURL.range(of:"www.collegiodeirettori.net/palio/")) != nil ){
            print("ciao")
            //print(stringaURL)
        }
        else{
                print(stringaURL)
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(request.url!)
            //UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: stringaURL)!)
            return false;
        }


}


    return true;
}
```

I already made a func that control if a link have to be opened in safari and that works but no for the mailto link..
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: are you trying to open this in the simulator or on the device?

Comment: Both of them and It doesn't work

Comment: @Alessandro, does your code actually get executed? Do you see in log your `print(stringaURL)` under debugger? `openURL` returns BOOL, could you log it as well? Also have you considered using [`MFMailComposeViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)? Also does your device have at least one e-mail account fully set up? See https://developer.apple.com/reference/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/1616879-cansendmail and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481029/when-will-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-cansendmail-return-no

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well I see in log print(stringaURL). I tried to execute the program under my iPad Mini and on the device I have a mail account which is configured with the Mail's app of iOS.

Comment: The error that appeared when I try to open a mail to link is
Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=mailto:biglietteriapalio@comune.asti.it}