# Mail sent successfully but don't recieve using MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am working in Xamarin ios. I need to implement mail functionality. I implemented the code and getting "Sent" in result. But it is not received by recipients. I am using MFMailComposeViewController to implement the mail functionality.

following is the code:

```
      if (MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail)
        {
            mailController = new MFMailComposeViewController();
            mailController.SetToRecipients(new string[] { abcd@gmail.com });
            mailController.SetSubject("");
            mailController.SetMessageBody("", false);
            mailController.Finished += (object s, MFComposeResultEventArgs args) =>
            {
                                   args.Controller.DismissViewController(true, null);
            };

        }
```

Comment: is this `abcd@gmail.com` valid mailID , if not chek your own mail

Comment: this is just for example, in my real code I am using my own email id

Comment: see this one for help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481029/when-will-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-cansendmail-return-no

Comment: I am getting true in "CanSendMail", and sending the mail successfully, but it is not received

Comment: did the real phone configured with valid email account .check this code in real device . and don't forget to check the network connectivity of the phone

Comment: Yes I am testing it in real device configured with valid email id.

Comment: You need to Present The controller on the view as Well. You have bind the finish event but havent dispayed the MFMailComposeViewController.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (MFMailComposeViewController.CanSendMail)
    {
        mailController = new MFMailComposeViewController();
        mailController.SetToRecipients(new string[] { abcd@gmail.com });
        mailController.SetSubject("");
        mailController.SetMessageBody("", false);

        mailController.Finished += (object s, MFComposeResultEventArgs args) =>
        {
                               args.Controller.DismissViewController(true, null);
        };
        this.ShowViewController(mailController, this);

    }
```

Mail Controller needs to be displayed on top of current controller. So Add the last line and try running the code.

It should open up a Email Window on top of your app. Where you can see all the details already filled up.

iOS doesnt allow you to send emails without opening up a email Client. So its on your user to either send the email or not.